# What these alphabets stands for?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

Sorry if this question is trivial but I couldn't find the answer in the internet,

In pytorch documentation I saw these large alphabets in formulas
like:
Input:(N, C, H^in, W^out)
link: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MaxPool2d.html

So what are these stands for and where
I can find the meaning of these alphabets.

Comment: Can you link the relevent parts of the documentation? I suspect it's nothing to do with pytorch and just used in an example

Comment: H, W denote the height and width of an image plane. And of course the subscripts in/out are for input or output.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks you !, what about N and C? btw i added a link so you can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are typical axis notations used in the PyTorch documentation to refer to the dimension sizes:

- **`N`**: batch size
- **`C`**: number of channels
- **`W`**: the width of the tensor
- **`H`**: the height of the tensor

Suffix `_in` and `_out` stand for the axis' corresponding input and output size respectively.

Comment: great answer, my like will be published soon i need reputation.